Swift Socket.IO v4 Not Connecting: Works in Basic Project but Fails in Complex App
I’m working on a Swift app using Socket.IO v4 for WebSocket communication, but I’m having trouble getting the socket to connect in my main app. I created a basic project with a simple connection setup, and it works perfectly there, but my more complex code in the main app fails to establish a connection.
Working Basic Project Code:
In this simple example, the connection works fine:
import SwiftUI
import SocketIO

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var socketManager: SocketManager!
    @State private var socket: SocketIOClient!

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Socket.IO Test").font(.largeTitle).padding()

            Button("Connect to Socket") {
                setupSocket()
                socket.connect()
            }
            .padding()

            Button("Emit Message") {
                do {
                    try sendMessage(siteId: 84)
                } catch {
                    fatalError()
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .onAppear {
            setupSocket()
        }
    }

    func setupSocket() {
        let url = URL(string: "https://link.to.server")!
        let jwtToken = "YOUR_JWT_TOKEN"

        socketManager = SocketManager(socketURL: url, config: [
            .log(true),
            .connectParams(["apiVersion": "2"]),
            .path("/integrations/pop/socket.io/"),
            .extraHeaders(["X-Auth-Token": jwtToken]),
            .forceWebsockets(true),
            .compress
        ])
        socket = socketManager.defaultSocket

        socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) { data, ack in
            print("Socket connected")
        }

        socket.on(clientEvent: .disconnect) { data, ack in
            print("Socket disconnected")
        }

        socket.on("recognition") { data, ack in
            print("Received data: \(data)")
        }
    }

    public func sendMessage(equipmentId: Int? = nil, siteId: Int? = nil) throws {
        var payload: [String: Any] = [:]
        if let equipmentId = equipmentId { payload["equipmentId"] = equipmentId }
        if let siteId = siteId { payload["siteId"] = siteId }

        let finalPayload = payload

        guard socket?.status == .connected || socket?.status == .connecting else {
            fatalError()
        }

        socket.emit("subscribe-recognitions", finalPayload)
    }
}

LOGS >
LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Adding handler for event: connect
LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Adding handler for event: disconnect
LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Adding handler for event: recognition
LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Adding handler for event: connect
LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Adding handler for event: disconnect
LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Adding handler for event: recognition
LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: statusChange with data: [connecting, 2]
LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Joining namespace /
LOG SocketManager: Tried connecting socket when engine isn't open. Connecting
LOG SocketManager: Adding engine
LOG SocketEngine: Starting engine. Server: https://link.to.server
LOG SocketEngine: Handshaking
LOG SocketManager: Manager is being released
LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Client is being released
LOG SocketEngine: Got message: 0{"sid":"randomNumber","upgrades":[],"pingInterval":30000,"pingTimeout":10000}
LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: websocketUpgrade with data: [["Upgrade": "websocket", "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000", "X-Amz-Cf-Pop": "randomNumber", "Sec-WebSocket-Accept": "A5BK/mgDa5PyeyMt/suZoN1Ogvo=", "Via": "1.1 randomNumber.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)", "X-Cache": "Miss from cloudfront", "Date": "Fri, 06 Sep 2024 14:04:51 GMT", "X-Amz-Cf-Id": "randomNumber-randomNumber ==", "Connection": "upgrade"]]
LOG SocketManager: Engine opened Connect
LOG SocketEngine: Writing ws: 0/, has data: false
LOG SocketEngineWebSocket: Sending ws: 0/, as type: 4
LOG SocketEngine: Got message: 40{"sid":"randomNumber"}
LOG SocketParser: Parsing 0{"sid":"randomNumber"}
LOG SocketParser: Decoded packet as: SocketPacket {type: 0; data: [{
    sid = "randomNumber";
}]; id: -1; placeholders: -1; nsp: /}
LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Socket connected
LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: statusChange with data: [connected, 3]
LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: connect with data: ["/", ["sid": randomNumber]]
Socket connected
LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Emitting: 2["subscribe-recognitions",{"siteId":84}], Ack: false
LOG SocketEngine: Writing ws: 2["subscribe-recognitions",{"siteId":84}] has data: false
LOG SocketEngineWebSocket: Sending ws: 2["subscribe-recognitions",{"siteId":84}] as type: 4

Non-Working Main App Code:
In my main app, I have a more complex socket setup, but for some reason, the socket doesn’t connect, and I’m not sure if it’s an order of operations issue or something else. Here’s the code for the main app’s SocketService class:
import Foundation
import Combine
import SocketIO

/// A service that manages WebSocket communication.
/// Available for macOS 15.0 and later.
///
///    - The SocketService is a singleton so use SocketService.shared.
/// - You will need to attach a subscriber to the messageSubject and errorSubject.
///    - You can check the connectionState to see if you are connected.
///    - Then you will need to call connect(with: AccessToken) then sendMessage.
///    - All received data from the server will be passed through to the messageSubject and any error to the errorSubject.
///    - You can also call disconnect to disconnect from the server.
@available(macOS 15.0, *)
public class SocketService {
    // MARK: Enums and Properties
    /// The state of the WebSocket connection.
    ///  - disconnected: The socket is not connected.
    ///  - connecting: The socket is attempting to connect.
    ///  - connected: The socket is connected.
    public enum ConnectionState {
        case disconnected
        case connecting
        case connected
    }
    /// The events that can be sent to the server.
    /// - recognition: A recognition event.
    /// - equipmentStateChanged: An equipment state change event.
    /// - paymentStateChanged: A payment state change event.
    /// - confirmAutomaticPurchase: A confirmation of an automatic purchase event.
    private enum SocketEvents: String, Codable, CaseIterable {
        case recognition = "recognition"
        case equipmentStateChanged = "equipment-state-changed"
        case paymentStateChanged = "payment-state-changed"
        case confirmAutomaticPurchase = "confirm-automatic-purchase"
    }
    /// The messages that can be sent to the server.
    /// - subscribeRecognitions: Subscribe to recognition events.
    /// - unsubscribeRecognitions: Unsubscribe from recognition events.
    /// - subscribeEquipment: Subscribe to equipment state change events.
    /// - unsubscribeEquipment: Unsubscribe from equipment state change events.
    /// - subscribePaymentStateChange: Subscribe to payment state change events.
    /// - unsubscribePaymentStateChange: Unsubscribe from payment state change events.
    /// - subscribeAutomaticPurcahseConfirmations: Subscribe to automatic purchase confirmation events.
    /// - unsubscribeAutomaticPurcahseConfirmations: Unsubscribe from automatic purchase confirmation events.
    public enum SocketMessage: String, Codable {
        case subscribeRecognitions = "subscribe-recognitions"
        case unsubscribeRecognitions = "unsubscribe-recognitions"
        case subscribeEquipment = "subscribe-equipment"
        case unsubscribeEquipment = "unsubscribe-equipment"
        case subscribePaymentStateChange = "subscribe-payment-state-change"
        case unsubscribePaymentStateChange = "unsubscribe-payment-state-change"
        case subscribeAutomaticPurcahseConfirmations = "subscribe-automatic-purchase-confirmations"
        case unsubscribeAutomaticPurcahseConfirmations = "unsubscribe-automatic-purchase-confirmations"
    }
    
    private var accessToken: AccessToken?
    private var socket: SocketIOClient?
    private let manager: SocketManager
    private var lastSentMessage: (event: SocketMessage, payload: [String: Any])?
    private let messageSubject = PassthroughSubject<Any, Never>()
    private let errorSubject = PassthroughSubject<APIError, Never>()
    
    @Published public private(set) var connectionState: ConnectionState = .disconnected
    
    // Singleton pattern updated for manual initialization to support dependency injection
    public static let shared = SocketService()
    
    // MARK: Inializer and Connection Methods
    /// Initializes a new instance of SocketService. This is a singleton so use .share. Pulls URL from configuration files.
    /// - Returns: A new instance of SocketService.
    /// - Throws: An error if the URL cannot be created.
    public init() {
        // Use URLComponentsBuilder to build the URL components
        do {
            let components = try URLComponentsBuilder.shared.buildComponents(path: "")
            
            // Create the URL from components
            guard let url = components.url else {
                fatalError("Invalid URL components for SocketService")
            }
            self.manager = SocketManager(socketURL: url, config:[
                
            ])
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to build URL components: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    /// Connects to the server using the provided token.
    /// - Parameter token: The token to use for authentication.
    ///
    /// On connect, we set the accessToken to provided token, check that we have a JWT token
    /// Then set the socket manager config, set up event handlers, and connect.
    public func connect(with token: AccessToken?) {
        self.accessToken = token
        
        guard let jwtToken = token?.jwtToken else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                self?.errorSubject.send(APIError.missingToken)
            }
            return
        }
        
        // Set up socket and connect:
        updateSocketConfig(with: jwtToken) {
            self.setupEventHandlers() {
                self.socket = self.manager.defaultSocket
                self.manager.connect()
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    /// Updates the socket configuration with the provided JWT token.
    /// This function sets various parameters for the socket connection, including compression, version, connection parameters,
    /// reconnection attempts and wait times, extra headers (including the JWT token for authentication), and logging.
    ///
    /// We've set reconnect to false because this library handles disconnects manually.
    private func updateSocketConfig(with jwtToken: String, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print(">>> updating socket config")
        
        manager.config = [
            .connectParams(["apiVersion": "2"]),
            .path("/integrations/pop/socket.io/"),
            .extraHeaders(["X-Auth-Token": jwtToken]),
            .forceWebsockets(true),
            .compress,
            .log(true)
            //        .reconnectAttempts(-1),
            //        .reconnectWait(1),
            //        .reconnectWaitMax(10)
        ]
        
        // Call the completion handler after config is set
        completion()
    }
    
    /// Disconnects socket and invalidates accessToken of on logout
    /// - Parameter withLogout: Bool for if logging out or on auto connect
    ///
    /// This removes all handlers for the socket, disconnects the socket, then the manager and updates connectionState
    /// If pass withLogout = true, it also sets accessToken to nil
    public func disconnect(withLogout: Bool = false) {
        if withLogout {
            self.accessToken = nil
            self.lastSentMessage = nil
        }
        // Clean up the socket instance
        socket?.removeAllHandlers()
        socket?.disconnect()
        manager.disconnect()
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            self?.connectionState = .disconnected
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: Reconnect after JWT Expires
    /// This function attempts to reconnect to the server.
    /// It first tries to refresh the access token. If successful, it updates the token in the Keychain,
    /// updates the access token for the socket service, updates the socket manager config with the new token,
    /// and then reconnects with the new token. If there was a last sent message, it resends it.
    /// If the refresh fails, it sends an error and tries to reconnect.
    /// If there is an error during the refresh (e.g., decoding errors or network issues), it sends an error and tries to reconnect.
    private func refreshTokenAndReconnect() async {
        // Exponential backoff strategy
        var delayInSeconds = 2
        let maxDelayInSeconds = 30
        let maxAttempts = 20
        var attemptCount = 0
        
        while attemptCount < maxAttempts {
            attemptCount += 1
            
            // Attempt to refresh the token and reconnect
            do {
                try await refreshAndReconnect()
                // Reconnection successful, exit the loop
                return
            } catch {
                // Reconnection failed, handle error
                self.errorSubject.send(APIError.webSocketError(error.localizedDescription))
            }
            
            // Exponential backoff delay
            delayInSeconds = min(delayInSeconds * 2, maxDelayInSeconds)
            try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: UInt64(delayInSeconds * 1_000_000_000))
        }
        
        // Max reconnection attempts reached, handle failure
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            self?.connectionState = .disconnected
        }
    }
    
    /// Hits login endpoint and on success will disconnect socket, save the new access token, and connect again with token
    ///
    /// This function will throw an error if login fails
    private func refreshAndReconnect() async throws {
        // Attempt to refresh the token
        guard let accessToken = self.accessToken else {
            throw APIError.missingToken
        }
        
        let loginAPI = LoginAPI()
        let result = try await loginAPI.refreshLogin(with: accessToken)
        
        switch result {
        case .success(let newToken):
            // disconnect, save token, and connect again
            disconnect()
            saveToken(newToken)
            connect(with: newToken)
        case .failure(let error):
            // Handle refresh failure
            throw error
        }
    }
    
    /// Saves token to keychain
    /// - Parameter newToken: accessToken for authentiation to save to keychain
    private func saveToken(_ newToken: AccessToken) {
        let keychainService = KeychainTokenService()
        try? keychainService.updateToken(type: .jwtToken, token: newToken.jwtToken ?? "")
        try? keychainService.updateToken(type: .refreshToken, token: newToken.refreshToken ?? "")
    }
    
    // MARK: handles unexpected disconnects
    /// Disconnects from socket and reconncts using existing access token
    /// Requires to already be connected and uses already existing token
    private func reconnectSocket() {
        self.disconnect() // Disconnect the current connection
        self.connect(with: self.accessToken) // Reconnect using the existing token
    }
    
    // MARK: Event Handling
    /// Setup the event handlers for the socket.
    private func setupEventHandlers(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        socket?.on(clientEvent: .connect) { [weak self] data, ack in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.messageSubject.send(["event": "connected"])
            }
        }
        
        socket?.on(clientEvent: .disconnect) { [weak self] data, ack in
            // Socket disconnected, reconnect:
            self?.reconnectSocket()
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.connectionState = .disconnected
                self?.messageSubject.send(["event": "disconnected"])
            }
        }
        
        socket?.on(clientEvent: .error) { [weak self] data, ack in
            if let errorInfo = data.first as? [String: Any], let errorCode = errorInfo["code"] as? String, errorCode == "expired-token" {
                // Detected expired token, attempt to reconnect which includes token refresh
                Task { [weak self] in
                    await self?.refreshTokenAndReconnect()
                }
            } else {
                // Handle other errors normally
                self?.errorSubject.send(APIError.webSocketError(data.first ?? "Error"))
            }
        }
        
        socket?.on(clientEvent: .statusChange) { [weak self] args, _ in
            if let status = args[0] as? SocketIOStatus {
                switch status {
                case .connected:
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self?.connectionState = .connected
                    }
                    if let lastSentMessage = self?.lastSentMessage {
                        do {
                            try self?.sendMessage(event: lastSentMessage.event, siteId: lastSentMessage.payload["siteId"] as? Int)
                        } catch {
                            print(">>>>> error sending message")
                        }
                    }
                case .connecting:
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self?.connectionState = .connecting
                    }
                case .disconnected, .notConnected:
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self?.connectionState = .disconnected
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        socket?.on(SocketEvents.recognition.rawValue) { [self] data, ack in
            handleEvent(data)
        }
        
        socket?.on(SocketEvents.equipmentStateChanged.rawValue) { [self] data, ack in
            handleEvent(data)
        }
        
        socket?.on(SocketEvents.paymentStateChanged.rawValue) { [self] data, ack in
            handleEvent(data)
        }
        
        socket?.on(SocketEvents.confirmAutomaticPurchase.rawValue) { [self] data, ack in
            handleEvent(data)
        }
        
        // Call the completion handler after config is set
        completion()
    }
    
    /// Handles the event data and sends it to the messageSubject.
    /// - Parameter data: The data to handle.
    private func handleEvent(_ data: [Any]) {
        if let messageData = data.first as? [String: Any] {
            // Function to decode JSON data
            func decode<T: Decodable>(_ type: T.Type, from dictionary: [String: Any]) -> T? {
                guard let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary, options: []) else {
                    return nil
                }
                do {
                    // Need to set the date decoding strategy first so Dates are decoded correctly
                    let formatter = DateFormatter()
                    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)
                    return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
                } catch {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.errorSubject.send(APIError.jsonDecodingError(message: "Failed event decode: \(error)"))
                    }
                    return nil
                }
            }
            
            // Determine event type based on incoming data
            var event: SocketEvents? = nil
            if messageData["state"] != nil {
                event = .equipmentStateChanged
            } else if messageData["alprCtrlId"] != nil {
                event = .recognition
            }
            
            // Proceed based on determined event type
            guard let determinedEvent = event else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.messageSubject.send(["event": "unknown", "data": messageData])
                }
                return
            }
            
            switch determinedEvent {
            case .equipmentStateChanged:
                guard let equipmentStateData: EquipmentStateData = decode(EquipmentStateData.self, from: messageData) else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.errorSubject.send(APIError.jsonDecodingError(message: "Failed equipmentStateChanged decode"))
                    }
                    return
                }
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.messageSubject.send(["event": determinedEvent.rawValue, "data": EventData.equipmentStateChanged(equipmentStateData)])
                }
                
            case .recognition:
                guard let recognitionData: SiteRecognition = decode(SiteRecognition.self, from: messageData) else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.errorSubject.send(APIError.jsonDecodingError(message: "Failed recognition decode"))
                    }
                    return
                }
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.messageSubject.send(["event": determinedEvent.rawValue, "data": EventData.recognition(recognitionData)])
                }
                
            default:
                // TODO: handle rest of events
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.messageSubject.send(["event": "unknown", "data": messageData])
                }
            }
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.errorSubject.send(APIError.jsonDecodingError(message: "Failed handleEvent decode"))
            }
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: Message Sending
    /// Sends a message to the server.
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - eventName: *SocketMessage*The name of the event to send.
    ///   - equipmentId: *optional, Int* The ID of the equipment to send the message to.
    ///   - siteId: *optional, Int* The ID of the site to send the message to.
    public func sendMessage(event eventName: SocketMessage, equipmentId: Int? = nil, siteId: Int? = nil) throws {
        var payload: [String: Any] = [:]
        if let equipmentId = equipmentId { payload["equipmentId"] = equipmentId }
        if let siteId = siteId { payload["siteId"] = siteId }
        
        let finalPayload = payload
        
        // always save last message for resend if needed:
        self.lastSentMessage = (event: eventName, payload: finalPayload)
        
        guard socket?.status == .connected || socket?.status == .connecting else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.errorSubject.send(APIError.webSocketConnectionFailed)
            }
            throw APIError.webSocketConnectionFailed
        }
        
        self.socket?.emit(eventName.rawValue, finalPayload)
    }
    
    // MARK: Publishing
    /// A publisher for messages received from the server.
    public var messages: AnyPublisher<Any, Never> {
        messageSubject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    /// A publisher for errors received from the server.
    public var errors: AnyPublisher<APIError, Never> {
        errorSubject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}


LOGS >
LOG SocketManager: Adding engine
LOG SocketEngine: Starting engine. Server: https://link.to.server
LOG SocketEngine: Handshaking
LOG SocketEngine: Got message: 0{"sid":"randomNumber","upgrades":[],"pingInterval":30000,"pingTimeout":10000}
LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: websocketUpgrade with data: [["Upgrade": "websocket", "X-Cache": "Miss from cloudfront", "Date": "Fri, 06 Sep 2024 14:01:11 GMT", "Via": "1.1 randomNumbers.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)", "X-Amz-Cf-Pop": "randomNumber-P1", "Connection": "upgrade", "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000", "Sec-WebSocket-Accept": "randomNumbers", "X-Amz-Cf-Id": "randomNumbers"]]
LOG SocketManager: Engine opened Connect

What I’ve Tried:
1.  I created a basic project to isolate the problem, and it connects just fine.
2.  Checked the order of operations to ensure the socket is being configured correctly.
3.  Tried using different SocketManager configurations, but no success.

My Question:
What could be causing the socket to not connect in the main app when it works in the basic project? Could this be an issue with the order of operations or some conflict with other parts of the app?
Environment:
•   iOS 16
•   Socket.IO v4
•   Swift 5.8

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
** I know it's not ideal to manually do a reconnect, but we are dealing with a token issue from the backend and are required to. That said, it's not even getting to that point so please ignore that.

There are moments when I question my life choices and wonder if this career was the right path. This is one of those moments. The reason the issue occurred was that I was calling manager.connect() instead of socket.connect(). Make sure to use the correct method.
